# Acidity of carboxylic acids

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

is there a reliable database with the pKa of halogenated carboxylic acids? I am also looking for the pKa of ethanoic acid substituted with other electronegative elements (like sulfur and oxygen).

Comment: You might want to try “Dissociation Constants of Organic Acids and Bases” in CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics.

Comment: With some effort, you may retrieve some data from one of the now preserved public [Reich collections](https://organicchemistrydata.org/hansreich/resources/pka/), e.g., pages 4  and following in [William's compilation](https://organicchemistrydata.org/hansreich/resources/pka/pka_data/pka-compilation-williams.pdf). Note, water needn't to be the only solvent to record these data, [this signpost](http://tera.chem.ut.ee/~ivo/HA_UT/) for example hints to many additional primary references about pKa based on experiment or/and computation, e.g. in acetonitrile / MeCN.